# Jmeter - Can't uppload csv file

Tags: jmeter

When i try to uppload file using Jmeter

I use 'File Upload section' like:

Filepath as:${filesUpploadPath}BatchReverse.csv

ParameterName as: file

MIME type: text/plain

[image]

[image]

[image]

Request

POST data:
--TQVDXTBd3I5-r4QtHZ2WSa5B2rsQKtLv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="BatchReverse.csv"
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

--AzTQVDXTBd3I5-r4QtHZ2WSa5B2rsQKtLv--

Response
{"errors":[{"type":"FATAL","errorCode":"VALIDATION","message":"Missing required parameter fileType."}]}

Any suggestion?

Comment: Isn't error from your application *Missing required parameter fileType*?

Comment: Correct. i am sending empty. any idea how should be populated 'Parameters' section?

Comment: I think your MIME type should be "text/csv"

Comment: Still the same. "errors":[{"type":"FATAL","errorCode":"VALIDATION","message":"Missing required parameter fileType."}]}

Comment: I suggest you check the parameters of this API using your web browser or a web debugging proxy like fiddler, and then add the required parameters on your http sampler.

Comment: Actually you helped me a lot. like this i solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your "Parameter Name" is wrong, you're using `file` and your application seems to be expecting `fileType`

The easiest way of building a proper file upload request is just [recording](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter/) it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

The only thing you need to do is to copy the file you're uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, this way JMeter will be able to properly construct the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

Once you get the "good" configuration and validate it using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener you can [parameterize and correlate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) the request as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Jmeter recorder, and i supposed to used: 
-MIME type as: application/vnd.ms-excel
-Parameters : fileType: REVERSALS